# Optimise postgres query for pull the top 5 records across unique users

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I have a large database table full of game race times - many for each user. Indexed on time_ms. Many millions of rows.

| id | user_id | time_ms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 156 |
| 2 | 23 | 123 |
| 3 | 45 | 345 |
| 4 | 45 | 333 |
| 5 | 23 | 545 |
| 6 | 66 | 923 |
| 7 | 91 | 648 |
| 8 | 103 | 987 |
| 9 | 45 | 333 |
| 10 | 23 | 545 |
| 11 | 66 | 923 |
| 12 | 91 | 648 |
| 13 | 103 | 987 |

I want to fetch the top 5 user times, but I don't want the same user in the top 5 repeated multiple times.

I am currently doing it like this, but doesn't seem like the fastest way to do it

```
SELECT min(time_ms), user_id
from races
group by user_id,
order by min(time_ms) 
limit 5
```

Because there is an index on time_ms, I feel like it could be faster because my query has to group the entire table by user_id and then pick the top 5.
Instead, it seems that a better query would use the index to pull the lowest 5 times across 5 different users.

Is there a quicker way to do this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty weird to talk about the most efficient way to implement it, without even showing us the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` of the current way of implementing it, or to say you want to make it faster, but without saying how fast it already is.

But yes, PostgreSQL is missing an efficient way to do this.  That would be a fast-starting hash aggregate, which does not exist.  It would have to be based on knowing that the first row it sees with a given hash key will also be the one emitted, which is a rather esoteric bit of knowledge.

But you can kind of implement that yourself in half-hearted way.

```
SELECT min(time_ms), user_id
from (select * from races order by time_ms limit 500) foo
group by user_id
order by min(time_ms) 
limit 5;
```

The problem with this method is there is really no way to know for sure that 500 for the inner LIMIT is enough to guarantee 5 distinct users.  If the top 4 users dominate all 500 best times, you won't get the right answer out.